# Why NodeJS API running on AppEngine gives 500 error when response is too Big?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am running a Node JS Rest API on Google App Engine which queries firebase realtime database.

Whenever the response payload from the API is too big, the API gives 500 error.

The code works absolutely fine for the same data set when I run the code locally. Looks like the problem is with AppEngine Environment.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [documented limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#response_limits) from the App Engine Standard environment for Nodejs. This is actually a limit from the URLFetch service and cannot be increased.

Note that that the App Engine Flexible environment [doesn't have this limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#response_limits_2). You may want to switch environment in case you can't reduce your response size.